# How can we handle duplicated rows after merging two dataframes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have two dataframes that look like this.

```
import pandas as pd
 
# initialize list of lists
expenses = [[2020, 108, 76848.94], [2020, 108, 42488.51]]
 
# Create the pandas DataFrame
expenses = pd.DataFrame(expenses, columns = ['Year', 'ID', 'Expense'])
expenses['ID'] = expenses['ID'].astype(str)
```

[image]

```
# initialize list of lists
revenues = [[2020, 108, 'NRG CENTER', 380121.25], [2020, 108, 'NRG STADIUM Area1', 500655.83], [2020, 108, 'NRG STADIUM Area2', 500655.83], [2020, 108, 'NRG STADIUM Area3', 338153.03], [2020, 108, 'NRG CENTER BB', 70846.37]]
 
# Create the pandas DataFrame
revenues = pd.DataFrame(revenues, columns = ['Year', 'ID', 'Name', 'Revenue'])
revenues['ID'] = revenues['ID'].astype(str)
```

[image]

Now, merge.

```
df_final = pd.merge(expenses, 
                revenues,
                left_on=['ID','Year'],
                right_on=['ID','Year'],
                how='inner')

df_final
```

When I merge the two together, I get this.

[image]

I tried to handle this a couple different ways. I tried this.

```
expenses_nodups = expenses.drop_duplicates()
df_final = pd.merge(revenues , expenses_nodups , on=['ID'])
df_final
```

That gives me dupes. So, I tried this.

```
df_final.drop_duplicates(keep=False,inplace=True)
df_final
```

That also gives me dupes.

I have a 'Name' field only in the revenue table, but nothing like this in the expense table. The expense table just has Year, ID, and Expense.

Why do we get these dupes?
How can I handle this dupe issue?

Comment: Can you show your expected output? The year and Id columns in your tables have only single values, because of this it is not surprising that you get all combinations when merging.

Comment: There are no duplicates across your rows . . . each row is unique

Comment: Can you specify which columns need to be unique?

Comment: I think I found a way to correct this. I can get unique revenue data points, and for repeating expenses, I can divide by the count. Why, though, do we get all these dupes? Just because we can't match records on 'Name'? It kind of makes sense, but I don't totally understand it.